# How to put date from mysql database into JFreeChart graph?

Tags: java, mysql, date, jfreechart

I have faced with a problem of putting date on my JFreeChart graph.
I read the double value and date value from my local MySql database but I cannot put date onto the graph.

Here is my useless tryings

```
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Dynamic");

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.size(); i++) {
        series.add(ch.get(i) * * *.get_date() * * *
        ,ch.get(i).get_pro());
    }

    XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Title", "Date", "Buy",
            xyDataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true, true, true);
    JFrame add = new DynamicCurrency(ch);
    add.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart));
    add.setVisible(true);
```

I bold the place where the mistake occurs.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getTime()` method which returns a `long` and cast it to `double`:

```
series.add((double) ch.get(i).get_date().getTime(), ch.get(i).get_pro());
```

Comment: Do you know whether is ts possible to convert date to normal format when showing it on graph?

Comment: Thanks once more for your advice but I again have a mistake=(

Comment: I add DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: and got  org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis

Comment: The `getDomainAxis()` method must return a `ValueAxis` which is a superclass of `NumberAxis` and `DateAxis`.

Comment: I see but nevertheless I got this mistake

Comment: org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis

Comment: import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

Comment: DateFormat TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        ValueAxis axis = (ValueAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        ((DateAxis) axis).setDateFormatOverride(TIMESTAMP);